# How to make view the size of another view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to recreate a portion of the Twitter iOS app to learn SwiftUI and am wondering how to dynamically change the width of one view to be the width of another view. In my case, to have the underline be the same width as the Text view.

I have attached a screenshot to try and better explain what I'm referring to. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Also here is the code I have so far:

```
import SwiftUI

struct GridViewHeader : View {

    @State var leftPadding: Length = 0.0
    @State var underLineWidth: Length = 100

    var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Tweets")
                    .tapAction {
                        self.leftPadding = 0

                }
                Spacer()
                Text("Tweets & Replies")
                    .tapAction {
                        self.leftPadding = 100
                    }
                Spacer()
                Text("Media")
                    .tapAction {
                        self.leftPadding = 200
                }
                Spacer()
                Text("Likes")
            }
            .frame(height: 50)
            .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            HStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(width: self.underLineWidth, height: 2, alignment: .bottom)
                    .padding(.leading, leftPadding)
                    .animation(.basic())
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's an important question. And i don't know generally how to get size of everything in SwiftUI or for example x and y of ScrollView. :(

Comment: I *think* you are missing an important piece of what SwiftUI (and declarative programming as a whole) is about. Could be wrong though. Have you considered making **each** `Text` and `Rectangle` it's own "custom view" - both in code and in layout - and incorporating the underscore as part of that? (1) Design your `View` to have a single Text with an underscore - even if it takes a ZStack and a Rectangle. Trust that it will *not* have padding. (2) Now place this view into a rectangle *with* padding if you need it. This is a *single* view. **Don't worry about size, worry about hierarchy.**

Comment: @Sajad_Behesti, If you need to *size* something just do it. BUT - if you don't, let SwiftUI do it for the device it's on. As for scroll views, use a `List`. For both of you, I'd recommend watching two (or more) WWDC sessions - introducing SwiftUI ( https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/204/ ) and SwiftUI Essentials (  https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/216/ ). It's a different mindset than `UIKit` but worth the time.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

***I have written a detailed explanation about using GeometryReader, view preferences and anchor preferences. The code below uses those concepts. For further information on how they work, check this article I posted: https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-1/***

The solution below, will properly animate the underline:

[image]

I struggled to make this work and I agree with you. Sometimes, you just need to be able to pass up or down the hierarchy, some framing information. In fact, the WWDC2019 session 237 (Building Custom Views with SwiftUI), explains that views communicate their sizing continuously. It basically says Parent proposes size to child, childen decide how they want to layout theirselves and communicate back to the parent. How they do that? I suspect the anchorPreference has something to do with it. However it is very obscure and not at all documented yet. The API is exposed, but grasping how those long function prototypes work... that's a hell I do not have time for right now.

I think Apple has left this undocumented to force us rethink the whole framework and forget about "old" UIKit habits and start thinking declaratively. However, there are still times when this is needed. Have you ever wonder how the background modifier works? I would love to see that implementation. It would explain a lot! I'm hoping Apple will document preferences in the near future. I have been experimenting with custom PreferenceKey and it looks interesting.

Now back to your specific need, I managed to work it out. There are two dimensions you need (the x position and width of the text). One I get it fair and square, the other seems a bit of a hack. Nevertheless, it works perfectly.

The x position of the text I solved it by creating a custom horizontal alignment. More information on that check session 237 (at minute 19:00). Although I recommend you watch the whole thing, it sheds a lot of light on how the layout process works.

The width, however, I'm not so proud of... ;-) It requires DispatchQueue to avoid updating the view while being displayed. ***UPDATE: I fixed it in the second implementation down below***

### First implementation

```swift
extension HorizontalAlignment {
    private enum UnderlineLeading: AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in d: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            return d[.leading]
        }
    }

    static let underlineLeading = HorizontalAlignment(UnderlineLeading.self)
}


struct GridViewHeader : View {

    @State private var activeIdx: Int = 0
    @State private var w: [CGFloat] = [0, 0, 0, 0]

    var body: some View {
        return VStack(alignment: .underlineLeading) {
            HStack {
                Text("Tweets").modifier(MagicStuff(activeIdx: $activeIdx, widths: $w, idx: 0))
                Spacer()
                Text("Tweets & Replies").modifier(MagicStuff(activeIdx: $activeIdx, widths: $w, idx: 1))
                Spacer()
                Text("Media").modifier(MagicStuff(activeIdx: $activeIdx, widths: $w, idx: 2))
                Spacer()
                Text("Likes").modifier(MagicStuff(activeIdx: $activeIdx, widths: $w, idx: 3))
                }
                .frame(height: 50)
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            Rectangle()
                .alignmentGuide(.underlineLeading) { d in d[.leading]  }
                .frame(width: w[activeIdx],  height: 2)
                .animation(.linear)
        }
    }
}

struct MagicStuff: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var activeIdx: Int
    @Binding var widths: [CGFloat]
    let idx: Int

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Group {
            if activeIdx == idx {
                content.alignmentGuide(.underlineLeading) { d in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { self.widths[self.idx] = d.width }

                    return d[.leading]
                }.onTapGesture { self.activeIdx = self.idx }

            } else {
                content.onTapGesture { self.activeIdx = self.idx }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Update: Better implementation without using DispatchQueue

My first solution works, but I was not too proud of the way the width is passed to the underline view.

I found a better way of achieving the same thing. It turns out, the **background** modifier is very powerful. It is much more than a modifier that can let you decorate the background of a view.

The basic steps are:

1. Use `Text("text").background(TextGeometry())`. TextGeometry is a custom view that has a parent with the same size as the text view. That is what .background() does. Very powerful.
2. In my implementation of **TextGeometry** I use GeometryReader, to get the geometry of the parent, which means, I get the geometry of the Text view, which means I now have the width.
3. Now to pass the width back, I am using **Preferences**. There's zero documentation about them, but after a little experimentation, I think preferences are something like "view attributes" if you like. I created my custom **PreferenceKey**, called **WidthPreferenceKey** and I use it in TextGeometry to "attach" the width to the view, so it can be read higher in the hierarchy.
4. Back in the ancestor, I use **onPreferenceChange** to detect changes in the width, and set the widths array accordingly.

It may all sound too complex, but the code illustrates it best. Here's the new implementation:

```swift
import SwiftUI

extension HorizontalAlignment {
    private enum UnderlineLeading: AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in d: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            return d[.leading]
        }
    }

    static let underlineLeading = HorizontalAlignment(UnderlineLeading.self)
}

struct WidthPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue = CGFloat(0)

    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = nextValue()
    }

    typealias Value = CGFloat
}


struct GridViewHeader : View {

    @State private var activeIdx: Int = 0
    @State private var w: [CGFloat] = [0, 0, 0, 0]

    var body: some View {
        return VStack(alignment: .underlineLeading) {
            HStack {
                Text("Tweets")
                    .modifier(MagicStuff(activeIdx: $activeIdx, idx: 0))
                    .background(TextGeometry())
                    .onPreferenceChange(WidthPreferenceKey.self, perform: { self.w[0] = $0 })

                Spacer()

                Text("Tweets & Replies")
                    .modifier(MagicStuff(activeIdx: $activeIdx, idx: 1))
                    .background(TextGeometry())
                    .onPreferenceChange(WidthPreferenceKey.self, perform: { self.w[1] = $0 })

                Spacer()

                Text("Media")
                    .modifier(MagicStuff(activeIdx: $activeIdx, idx: 2))
                    .background(TextGeometry())
                    .onPreferenceChange(WidthPreferenceKey.self, perform: { self.w[2] = $0 })

                Spacer()

                Text("Likes")
                    .modifier(MagicStuff(activeIdx: $activeIdx, idx: 3))
                    .background(TextGeometry())
                    .onPreferenceChange(WidthPreferenceKey.self, perform: { self.w[3] = $0 })

                }
                .frame(height: 50)
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            Rectangle()
                .alignmentGuide(.underlineLeading) { d in d[.leading]  }
                .frame(width: w[activeIdx],  height: 2)
                .animation(.linear)
        }
    }
}

struct TextGeometry: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            return Rectangle().fill(Color.clear).preference(key: WidthPreferenceKey.self, value: geometry.size.width)
        }
    }
}

struct MagicStuff: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var activeIdx: Int
    let idx: Int

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Group {
            if activeIdx == idx {
                content.alignmentGuide(.underlineLeading) { d in
                    return d[.leading]
                }.onTapGesture { self.activeIdx = self.idx }

            } else {
                content.onTapGesture { self.activeIdx = self.idx }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: great solution. I am still struggling to understand how alignmentGuide works. Like in WWDC2019 session 237, I haven't got what is going on under the hood  at 22:50. When we say viewDimension[.bottom] is a Length (CGFloat), what does that length represent, view's height?

Comment: It is rather confusing. It seems that .bottom is indirectly the height. If .top == 0 then .bottom would be reflecting the height. I don't know... With so little documentation, it will require some trial an error in different scenarios, in order to get to a confident conclusion.

Comment: It's a very clever trick, I will try to apply it. But I wonder if it might be possible to use _two_ custom alignments, one on the left and one on the right end, to get the width?

Comment: Btw maybe you know the answer to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56822791/hug-subviews-in-swiftui

Comment: @Gusutafu I already tried, but failed miserably to use the double custom alignment approach. Let me know if you are successful. By the way, since then I figured out how to use anchor preferences, which I think is the way to go. I am writing an article and will post a link here for further reference once it's finished.

Comment: @kontiki have you encountered issues  (unexpected results) with PreferenceKey when extracting views to separate custom views? I have an example here: https://gist.github.com/kremizask/f6a27ee9ae3c81f3f63ba9443785d3be

Comment: @kontiki where did you define Length? I tried running this code on my Xcode and it says give me the undeclared type 'Length' error

Comment: Hi @bain, this is an old answer. In early versions of SwiftUI there was a type named `Length`. Around beta 3 or so, it was replaced by CGFloat.

Comment: @kontiki the .alignmentGuide for Rectangle() /or any other View placed in the same VStack/ is redundant, if returns UnderlineLeading.default value. Using that masks how it works and could lead to misunderstanding the SwiftuUI layout system. removing it gives you the same behavior

Comment: @kontiki I may be asking a bit much but would you be willing to give an up to date solution for the most recent SwiftUI? This is a genius solution that I would love to implement, however it seems with this most recent update I am getting error after error. I did change the Length to CGFloat which worked, but getting another error.

Comment: Hi @bain Updated code to latest API. Replaced Length with CGFloat. .basic animation with .linear, and .onTapAction with .tagGesture.

Comment: I have a super-weird animation behaviour if this solution is used on a view inside `List`. If the content of the `List` changes its height when selecting a different title (the content is underneath the selectable titles), the underline does not move in straight horizontal line between the titles, but travels in arch. This is not reproducible with, say, `ScrollView`.

Comment: @kontiki can you now do this with iOS 16 SwiftUI Grid?

Answer (score 34):

First, to answer the question in the title, if you want to make a shape (view) fit to the size of another view, you can use an `.overlay()`.  The `.overlay()` gets offered its size from the view it is modifying.

In order to set offsets and widths in your Twitter recreation, you can use a `GeometryReader`.  The `GeometryReader` has the ability to find its `.frame(in:)` another coordinate space.

You can use `.coordinateSpace(name:)` to identify the reference coordinate space.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var width: CGFloat = 0
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("Tweets")
                .overlay(MoveUnderlineButton(offset: $offset, width: $width))
            Text("Tweets & Replies")
                .overlay(MoveUnderlineButton(offset: $offset, width: $width))
            Text("Media")
                .overlay(MoveUnderlineButton(offset: $offset, width: $width))
            Text("Likes")
                .overlay(MoveUnderlineButton(offset: $offset, width: $width))
        }
        .coordinateSpace(name: "container")
        .overlay(underline, alignment: .bottomLeading)
        .animation(.spring())
    }
    var underline: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(height: 2)
            .frame(width: width)
            .padding(.leading, offset)
    }
    struct MoveUnderlineButton: View {
        @Binding var offset: CGFloat
        @Binding var width: CGFloat
        var body: some View {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Button(action: {
                    self.offset = geometry.frame(in: .named("container")).minX
                    self.width = geometry.size.width
                }) {
                    Rectangle().foregroundColor(.clear)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. The `underline` view is is a 2 point high `Rectangle`, put in an `.overlay()` on top of the `HStack`.
2. The `underline` view is aligned to `.bottomLeading`, so that we can programmatically set its `.padding(.leading, _)` using a `@State` value.
3. The underline view's `.frame(width:)` is also set using a `@State` value.
4. The `HStack` is set as the `.coordinateSpace(name: "container")` so we can find the frame of our buttons relative to this.
5. The `MoveUnderlineButton` uses a `GeometryReader` to find its own `width` and `minX` in order to set the respective values for the `underline` view
6. The `MoveUnderlineButton` is set as the `.overlay()` for the `Text` view containing the text of that button so that its `GeometryReader` inherits its size from that `Text` view.

[image: Segmented with Underbar in action]

Comment: To enable default selection MoveUnderlineButton should have isActive property and 

.onAppear {
                    if self.isActive {
                        self.width = geometry.size.width
                    }
                }

should be added to button

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
import SwiftUI

var titles = ["Tweets", "Tweets & Replies", "Media", "Likes"]

struct GridViewHeader : View {

    @State var selectedItem: String = "Tweets"

    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 20) {
            ForEach(titles.identified(by: \.self)) { title in
                HeaderTabButton(title: title, selectedItem: self.$selectedItem)
                }
                .frame(height: 50)
        }.padding(.horizontal, 10)

    }
}

struct HeaderTabButton : View {
    var title: String

    @Binding var selectedItem: String

    var isSelected: Bool {
        selectedItem == title
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: { self.selectedItem = self.title }) {
                Text(title).fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)

                Rectangle()
                    .frame(height: 2, alignment: .bottom)
                    .relativeWidth(1)
                    .foregroundColor(isSelected ? Color.accentColor : Color.clear)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's what it looks like in preview:
[image: Preview screen]

Comment: Your solution does not animate. This is because the way you layout, is by creating the underline as 4 different views. The OP was hoping for a single underline that would slide and resize into position. I also posted my answer, which uses a single view for the underline, which moves and resizes accordingly.

Comment: Hmm, they didn't call that out in their question, but I also don't use Twitter, so maybe it's obvious if you do!

Comment: I'm not a twitter user either, that was just my interpretation. The OP said: "dynamically change the width of one view". He talks about "one" view, not 4. Hence, my assumption. I may be wrong though.

Answer (score 3):

Let me modestly suggest a slight modification of [this bright answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56661706/):
Version without using preferences:

```
import SwiftUI

extension HorizontalAlignment {
    private enum UnderlineLeading: AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in d: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            return d[.leading]
        }
    }

    static let underlineLeading = HorizontalAlignment(UnderlineLeading.self)
}


struct GridViewHeader : View {

    @State private var activeIdx: Int = 0
    @State private var w: [CGFloat] = [0, 0, 0, 0]

    var body: some View {
        return VStack(alignment: .underlineLeading) {
            HStack {
                Text("Tweets").modifier(MagicStuff(activeIdx: $activeIdx, widths: $w, idx: 0))
                Spacer()
                Text("Tweets & Replies").modifier(MagicStuff(activeIdx: $activeIdx, widths: $w, idx: 1))
                Spacer()
                Text("Media").modifier(MagicStuff(activeIdx: $activeIdx, widths: $w, idx: 2))
                Spacer()
                Text("Likes").modifier(MagicStuff(activeIdx: $activeIdx, widths: $w, idx: 3))
                }
                .frame(height: 50)
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            Rectangle()
                .alignmentGuide(.underlineLeading) { d in d[.leading]  }
                .frame(width: w[activeIdx],  height: 2)
                .animation(.linear)
        }
    }
}

struct MagicStuff: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var activeIdx: Int
    @Binding var widths: [CGFloat]
    let idx: Int

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        var w: CGFloat = 0
        return Group {
            if activeIdx == idx {
                content.alignmentGuide(.underlineLeading) { d in
                    w = d.width
                    return d[.leading]
                }.onTapGesture { self.activeIdx = self.idx }.onAppear(perform: {self.widths[self.idx] = w})

            } else {
                content.onTapGesture { self.activeIdx = self.idx }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Version using preferences and `GeometryReader`:

```
import SwiftUI

extension HorizontalAlignment {
    private enum UnderlineLeading: AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in d: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            return d[.leading]
        }
    }

    static let underlineLeading = HorizontalAlignment(UnderlineLeading.self)
}

struct WidthPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue = CGFloat(0)

    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = nextValue()
    }

    typealias Value = CGFloat
}


struct GridViewHeader : View {

    @State private var activeIdx: Int = 0
    @State private var w: [CGFloat] = [0, 0, 0, 0]

    var body: some View {
        return VStack(alignment: .underlineLeading) {
            HStack {
                Text("Tweets")
                    .modifier(MagicStuff(activeIdx: $activeIdx, idx: 0, widthStorage: $w))

                Spacer()

                Text("Tweets & Replies")
                    .modifier(MagicStuff(activeIdx: $activeIdx, idx: 1, widthStorage: $w))

                Spacer()

                Text("Media")
                    .modifier(MagicStuff(activeIdx: $activeIdx, idx: 2, widthStorage: $w))

                Spacer()

                Text("Likes")
                    .modifier(MagicStuff(activeIdx: $activeIdx, idx: 3, widthStorage: $w))

                }
                .frame(height: 50)
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: w[activeIdx],  height: 2)
                .animation(.linear)
        }
    }
}

struct MagicStuff: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var activeIdx: Int
    let idx: Int
    @Binding var widthStorage: [CGFloat]

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Group {

            if activeIdx == idx {
                content.background(GeometryReader { geometry in
                    return Color.clear.preference(key: WidthPreferenceKey.self, value: geometry.size.width)
                })
                .alignmentGuide(.underlineLeading) { d in
                    return d[.leading]
                }.onTapGesture { self.activeIdx = self.idx }
                    .onPreferenceChange(WidthPreferenceKey.self, perform: { self.widthStorage[self.idx] = $0 })


            } else {
                content.onTapGesture { self.activeIdx = self.idx }.onPreferenceChange(WidthPreferenceKey.self, perform: { self.widthStorage[self.idx] = $0 })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a super simple solution, although it doesn't account for the tabs being stretched full width - but that should just be minor additional math for calculating the padding.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct HorizontalTabs: View {

  private let tabsSpacing = CGFloat(16)

  private func tabWidth(at index: Int) -> CGFloat {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = tabs[index]
    let labelWidth = label.intrinsicContentSize.width
    return labelWidth
  }

  private var leadingPadding: CGFloat {
    var padding: CGFloat = 0
    for i in 0..<tabs.count {
      if i < selectedIndex {
        padding += tabWidth(at: i) + tabsSpacing
      }
    }
    return padding
  }

  let tabs: [String]

  @State var selectedIndex: Int = 0

  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
      HStack(spacing: tabsSpacing) {
        ForEach(0..<tabs.count, id: \.self) { index in
          Button(action: { self.selectedIndex = index }) {
            Text(self.tabs[index])
          }
        }
      }
      Rectangle()
        .frame(width: tabWidth(at: selectedIndex), height: 3, alignment: .bottomLeading)
        .foregroundColor(.blue)
        .padding(.leading, leadingPadding)
        .animation(Animation.spring())
    }
  }
}
```

---

`HorizontalTabs(tabs: ["one", "two", "three"])` renders this:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score -2):

You just need to specify a frame with a height within it. Here's an example :

```
VStack {
    Text("First Text Label")

    Spacer().frame(height: 50)    // This line

    Text("Second Text Label")
}
```

Answer (score -3):

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505043/how-to-make-view-the-size-of-another-view-in-swiftui/56661706#56661706) is very wonderful.

But it became a compilation error now, it corrected. (Xcode11.1)

This is a whole code.

```
extension HorizontalAlignment {
    private enum UnderlineLeading: AlignmentID {
        static func defaultValue(in d: ViewDimensions) -> CGFloat {
            return d[.leading]
        }
    }

    static let underlineLeading = HorizontalAlignment(UnderlineLeading.self)
}

struct WidthPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGFloat
    static var defaultValue = CGFloat(0)
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}


struct HorizontalTabsView : View {

    @State private var activeIdx: Int = 0
    @State private var w: [CGFloat] = [0, 0, 0, 0]

    var body: some View {
        return VStack(alignment: .underlineLeading) {
            HStack {
                Text("Tweets")
                    .modifier(MagicStuff(activeIdx: $activeIdx, idx: 0))
                    .background(TextGeometry())
                    .onPreferenceChange(WidthPreferenceKey.self, perform: { self.w[0] = $0 })

                Spacer()

                Text("Tweets & Replies")
                    .modifier(MagicStuff(activeIdx: $activeIdx, idx: 1))
                    .background(TextGeometry())
                    .onPreferenceChange(WidthPreferenceKey.self, perform: { self.w[1] = $0 })

                Spacer()

                Text("Media")
                    .modifier(MagicStuff(activeIdx: $activeIdx, idx: 2))
                    .background(TextGeometry())
                    .onPreferenceChange(WidthPreferenceKey.self, perform: { self.w[2] = $0 })

                Spacer()

                Text("Likes")
                    .modifier(MagicStuff(activeIdx: $activeIdx, idx: 3))
                    .background(TextGeometry())
                    .onPreferenceChange(WidthPreferenceKey.self, perform: { self.w[3] = $0 })

                }
                .frame(height: 50)
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)

            Rectangle()
                .alignmentGuide(.underlineLeading) { d in d[.leading]  }
                .frame(width: w[activeIdx],  height: 2)
                .animation(.default)
        }
    }
}

struct TextGeometry: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            return Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.clear)
                .preference(key: WidthPreferenceKey.self, value: geometry.size.width)
        }
    }
}

struct MagicStuff: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var activeIdx: Int
    let idx: Int

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Group {
            if activeIdx == idx {
                content.alignmentGuide(.underlineLeading) { d in
                    return d[.leading]
                }.onTapGesture { self.activeIdx = self.idx }

            } else {
                content.onTapGesture { self.activeIdx = self.idx }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct HorizontalTabsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HorizontalTabsView()
    }
}
```

Comment: If their code had errors, edit their original answer, not make your own answer.