# Hug subviews in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Dave Abrahams explained some of the mechanics of SwiftUI layouts in his WWDC19 talk about Custom Views, but he left out some bits and I have trouble getting my views properly sized.

**Is there a way for a View to tell its container that it is not making any space demands, but it will use all the space it is given? Another way to say it is that the container should hug its subviews.**

Concrete example, I want something like c:

[image: Some Texts inside a VStack]

If you have some `Text`s inside a `VStack` like in a), the `VStack` will adopt it's width to the widest subview.

If you add a `Rectangle` though as in b), it will expand as much as it can, until the `VStack` fills *its* container.

This indicates that `Text`s and `Rectangle`s are in different categories when it comes to layout, `Text` has a fixed size and a `Rectangle` is greedy. **But how can I communicate this to my container if I'm making my own `View`?**

The result I actually want to achieve is c). VStack should ignore Rectangle (or my custom view) when it determines its size, and then once it has done that, *then* it should tell Rectangle, or my custom view, how much space it can have.

Given that SwiftUI seems to layout bottom-up, maybe this is impossible, but it seems that there should be `some` way to achieve this.

Comment: I think you can get it to work by getting all text view widths, calculating the biggest and use it to set the frame width of the rectangle. Let me see if I can make it work and I'll post the answer.

Comment: Yeah using your trick it should be possible. I would even put the textviews as Content in a CustomView and let the CustomView add the rectangle. But it seems like there should be some modifier or something to tell views to behave in this way!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no modifier (AFAIK) to accomplish this, so here's my approach. If this is something you are going to use too often, it could be worth creating your own modifier.

Also note that here I am using standard preferences, but anchor preferences are even better. It is a heavy topic to explain here. I've written an article that you can check here: https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-1/

You can use the code below to accomplish what you are looking for.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MyRectPreference: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = [CGRect]

    static var defaultValue: [CGRect] = []

    static func reduce(value: inout [CGRect], nextValue: () -> [CGRect]) {
        value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    @State private var widestText: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello").background(RectGetter())
            Text("Wonderful World!").background(RectGetter())
            Rectangle().fill(Color.blue).frame(width: widestText, height: 30)
            }.onPreferenceChange(MyRectPreference.self, perform: { prefs in
                for p in prefs {
                    self.widestText = max(self.widestText, p.size.width)
                }
            })
    }
}

struct RectGetter: View {

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.clear)
                .preference(key: MyRectPreference.self, value: [geometry.frame(in: .global)])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is amazing, and it really works!

Comment: Glad it works ;-) Preferences are very useful to communicate information through the view hierarchy tree. It is unfortunate the documentation is almost entirely missing.

Comment: Oh no it doesn't actually work for my use case! Instead of textviews I have my own custom views, and it seems that they don't report their size to the geometry reader properly, so it thinks they have no size at all! Very strange, because they display properly

Comment: Can you post an example of a custom view that doesn’t work?

Comment: My custom view is very complex, so I will first make a simpler one. The weird thing is that if I have a stack of textviews as content the frame is properly reported, but if I add in my custom view in addition to the textviews, my frame reader again thinks that the total size is 0!

Comment: OK, so if I apply the RectGetter to a VStack of two texts, it works fine, but if I wrap one of the texts in "if true { Text("blabla") }" then it stops working! The texts still display and layout fine, but the rectgetter fails.

Comment: Do you mean: if true { Text("blabla").background(RectGetter()) }"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195754/discussion-between-kontiki-and-gusutafu).

Comment: Btw I "unanswered" your reply since I still have hopes for a "native" solution to this, but I still think your trick is extremely useful. I will re-answer it in a week if no other answer pops up!

Comment: That's alright. There are still many betas to come until the GM. Maybe we'll get lucky...

Comment: This is brilliant, but breaks for a `List` when the height of a collapsible list item changes as it expands-contracts. The size ends up larger than it began pre-expand.

Answer (score 6):

So I actually found a way to do this. First I tried putting Spacers around the views in various configurations, to try to push it together, but that didn't work. Then I realised I could perhaps use the .background modifier, and that actually did work. It seems to let the owning view calculate its size first, and then just takes that as its frame, which is exactly what I want.

This is just an example with some hacks to get the right height, but that is a small detail, and in my particular use case it is not needed. Probably not here either if you're clever enough.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 10) {
        Text("Short").background(Color.green)
        Text("A longer text").background(Color.green)
        Text("Dummy").opacity(0)
    }
    .background(backgroundView)
    .background(Color.red)
    .padding()
    .background(Color.blue)
}

var backgroundView: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 10) {
        Spacer()
        Spacer()
        Rectangle().fill(Color.yellow)
    }
}
```

The blue view and all the color backgrounds are of course just to make it easier to see.
This code produces this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The rectangle has the ideal size equal to 10x10 pt, but the ideal size is not enforced with the fixedSize modifier at the end of its implementation. That's why the Rectangle layout is fitting the expanded size instead of its ideal size (compressed size).

To illustrate it, I propose to create a new Rectangle:

```
struct RectangleWithForcedIdealSize: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle().fixedSize()
    }
}

struct RectangleWithForcedCustomIdealSize: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle().frame(idealWidth: 100, idealHeight: 100.fixedSize()
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
struct ExampleRectangleWithForcedIdealSizeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            Text("One")
            Text("Twenty")
            RectangleWithForcedIdealSize()
        }
    }
}
```

Example of Preview:

```
struct ExampleRectangleWithForcedIdealSizeViewPreview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ExampleRectangleWithForcedIdealSizeView()
            .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
            .border(Color.black)
    }
}
```