# Make parent view's width the width of the smallest child?

Tags: swiftui

How can I make a parent view's width the width of the smallest child?

I can learn the width of the child view using the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505043/how-to-make-view-the-size-of-another-view-in-swiftui) like so:

```swift
struct WidthPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue = CGFloat(0)

    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = nextValue()
    }

    typealias Value = CGFloat
}

struct TextGeometry: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            return Rectangle().fill(Color.clear).preference(key: WidthPreferenceKey.self, value: geometry.size.width)
        }
    }
}

struct Content: View {

    @State var width1: CGFloat = 0
    @State var width2: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Short")
              .background(TextGeometry())
              .onPreferenceChange(WidthPreferenceKey.self, perform: { self.width1 = $0 })
            Text("Loooooooooooong")
              .background(TextGeometry())
              .onPreferenceChange(WidthPreferenceKey.self, perform: { self.width2 = $0 })
        }
        .frame(width: min(self.width1, self.width2)) // This is always 0
    }

}
```

But the `VStack` has always width 0. It's like as if 
the line `.frame(width: min(self.width1, self.width2))` is being called
before the widths are set.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a logic bug, in that the system is technically doing exactly what you've told it to, but that result is not what you, as the programmer, intended.

Basically, VStack *wants* to shrink as much as possible to fit the size of its content. Likewise, Text views are *willing* to shrink as much as possible (truncating their contents) to fit inside their parent view. The only hard requirement you've given is that the initial frame of the VStack have width of 0. So the following sequence happens:

1. `width1` and `width2` are initialized to 0
2. The `VStack` sets its width to `min(0, 0)`
3. The `Text` views inside shrink to width 0
4. `WidthPreferenceKey.self` is set to 0
5. `.onPreferenceChange` sets `width1` and `width2`, which are already 0

All the constraints are satisfied, and SwiftUI happily stops layout.

Let's modify your code with the following:

1. Make `WidthPreferenceKey.Value` a typealias to `[CGFloat]` instead of `CGFloat`. This way, you can set as many preference key setters as you want, and they will just keep accumulating into an array.
2. Use one `.onPreferenceChange` call, which will find the minimum of all the read values, and set the single `@State var width: CGFloat` property
3. Add `.fixedSize()` to the `Text` views.

Like so:

```
struct WidthPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue = [CGFloat]()

    static func reduce(value: inout [CGFloat], nextValue: () -> [CGFloat]) {
        value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
    }

    typealias Value = [CGFloat]
}

struct TextGeometry: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            return Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.clear)
                .preference(key: WidthPreferenceKey.self,
                            value: [geometry.size.width])
        }
    }
}

struct Content: View {

    @State var width: CGFloat = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Short")
                .fixedSize()
                .background(TextGeometry())
            Text("Loooooooooooong")
                .fixedSize()
                .background(TextGeometry())
        }
        .frame(width: self.width)
        .clipped()
        .background(Color.red.opacity(0.5))
        .onPreferenceChange(WidthPreferenceKey.self) { preferences in
            print(preferences)
            self.width = preferences.min() ?? 0
        }
    }

}
```

Now the following happens:

1. `width` is initialized to 0
2. The `VStack` sets its width to 0
3. The `Text` views expand *outside* the VStack, since we've given permission with `.fixedSize()`
4. `WidthPreferenceKey.self` is set to `[42.5, 144.5]` (or something close)
5. `.onPreferenceChange` sets `width` to `42.5`
6. The `VStack` sets its width to `42.5` to satisfy its `.frame()` modifier.

All constraints are satisfied, and SwiftUI stops layout. Note that `.clipped()` is keeping the edges of the long `Text` view from displaying, even though they are technically outside the bounds of the `VStack`.