# SwiftUI Segmented Control Customizable

Tags: swiftui

I want to achieve such a control like this (https://github.com/Yalantis/Segmentio) in SwiftUI (but without image):

[image]

What would be the best approach?

Should I use a segmented control and customize it, like text in the middle and a bottom border?

Or should I use a ScrollView-->HStack-->XButtons?

This I already tried, but how should i animate the bottom border on selection change?
Is something possible in SwiftUI?

```
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 8, content: {
        Button(action: {
            print("Button pressed")
        }, label: {
            Text("Example Button")
                .padding(20)
        })
         ... button 2, ... button 3 and so on



     }).frame(height: 80, alignment: .leading)
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56505043/how-to-make-view-the-size-of-another-view-in-swiftui

Answer (score 0):

```
struct MyTestView2: View {
  
    struct Disasterd: Identifiable {
        var id: Int
        var systemImage: String
        var text: String
    }
    
    @State var disasters = [Disasterd(id: 1, systemImage: "wind", text: "wind"),
                            Disasterd(id: 2, systemImage: "sun.max", text: "sun"),
                            Disasterd(id: 3, systemImage: "cloud.rain", text: "rain")]
    
    @State var selected = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("with image")
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 8, content: {
                    ForEach(disasters, id:\.id) { dis in
                        Button(action: {
                            print("Button pressed")
                            selected = dis.id
                        }, label: {
                            VStack {
                                Image(systemName: dis.systemImage)
                                    .font(.system(size: 40))
                                    .frame(width: 80, height: 50)
                                Text(dis.text)
                                    .padding(.top,20)
                                Rectangle()
                                    .frame(width: 80, height: 5)
                                    .foregroundColor(selected == dis.id ? .orange:.white)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                 })
                .animation(.default)
                .frame(height: 180, alignment: .leading)
            }
            Text("without image")
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 8, content: {
                    ForEach(disasters, id:\.id) { dis in
                        Button(action: {
                            print("Button pressed")
                            selected = dis.id
                        }, label: {
                            VStack {
                                Text(dis.text)
                                    .frame(width: 80, height: 20)
                                    .padding(.top,20)
                                Rectangle()
                                    .frame(width: 80, height: 5)
                                    .foregroundColor(selected == dis.id ? .orange:.white)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                 })
                .animation(.default)
                .frame(height: 180, alignment: .leading)
            }
        }
    }
        
}
```